# Lightbox showing images twice in html

Tags: html

I am using html website and added lightbox in it. when i open an image I noticed that it showing each image twice. So if i have 3 imagers then the result will be:

image1, image2, image3, image1, image2, image3

Please see also my html code. Hopefully someone have an idea what is going wrong.

```
<a href="images/i61.png" data-lightbox="dfwerasrsrg" data-title="i6"><img src="images/pic02.png" alt="" class="image image-left" </a>
<a href="images/i64.png" data-lightbox="dfwerasrsrg" data-title="i6"></a>
<a href="images/i62.png" data-lightbox="dfwerasrsrg" data-title="i6"></a>
<a href="images/i63.png" data-lightbox="dfwerasrsrg" data-title="i6"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid for a start as you forgot to close the img tag:

Change:

```
<a href="images/i61.png" data-lightbox="dfwerasrsrg" data-title="i6"><img src="images/pic02.png" alt="" class="image image-left" </a>
```

To:

```
<a href="images/i61.png" data-lightbox="dfwerasrsrg" data-title="i6"><img src="images/pic02.png" alt="something descriptive" class="image image-left" /></a>
```